# Is jailbreak the same as android root? What are the exact privileges that jailbreak provide?

Tags: ios, root, jailbreak, chroot

Everywhere on the internet, jailbreak is described as equivalent to rooting on an Android, but is it true?

For example, Android is based on linux kernel, so rooting means to flash the su binary hence giving you the "sudo" or "root" privileges as in linux Ubuntu. What is the equivalent process involved in an iOS jailbreak? Does it give a user the ability to run a terminal with sudo privileges and complete control over the device?

As far as I understand, iOS is based on BSD kernel which implements the jails by making use of chroot syscall and jailbreak means to remove this protection by using an exploitation. But is this equivalent to root privileges or is root locked even after you jailbreak your device?

I would be very very grateful if someone can clear up on this. No article or book mentions this in the detail that I require.

Comment: what detail do you require?

Answer (score -1):

5 minute Google search would have given you all the answers you need... you gain root access, there are multiple threads on r/jailbreak, such as [this advice regarding sudo password](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/7q67ot/tutorial_dont_forget_to_change_root_passwords/) or [this guy asking about terminal](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/84hu4m/question_where_can_i_get_mterminal_for_ios_11/).